# JSF Navigation using h:SelectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, navigation, xhtml

Morning everyone, I have a question in regards to JSF navigation and using  for navigation. My navigation was working fine until I put a three .xhtml files into subfolders. I have Home.xhtml, A.xhtml, B.xhtml, and C.xhtml all in the same folder. Upon putting A,B,and C.xhtml into subfolders A,B, and C, and then navigating from Home.xhtml, to A.xhtml, then to B.xhtml, I get this error: "/A/B/B.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource". Obviously the pages are stacking in the URL, but I'm not sure why.

My Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="company")
@SessionScoped
public class CompanyBean implements Serializable {

private static Map<String, Object> companyValue;
public String value;
boolean temp;


public static Map<String, Object> getCompanyValues() {
    return companyValue;
}

public boolean getTemp() {

    if (Env.isProd()==true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void setTemp()
{
    temp=Env.isProd();
}


public static void setCompanyValues(Map<String, Object> companyValues) {
    CompanyBean.companyValue = companyValues;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public CompanyBean()
{
companyValue=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
companyValue.put("Select Company", "choose");
companyValue.put("AE", "AE/AE.xhtml");
companyValue.put("BP", "BP/BP.xhtml");
companyValue.put("CBK", "CBK/CBK.xhtml");
}

public Map<String,Object> getCompanyValue() {
    return companyValue;
}

public void navigate(ValueChangeEvent event)
{
    String page= event.getNewValue().toString();
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(page);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

My jsf code:

```
<h:form>
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{company.value}" valueChangeListener="#{company.navigate}"       onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <f:selectItems value="#{company.companyValue}" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Sorry if this has been answered as it is morning and I am half awake.

Comment: Probably because you are redirecting to a relative URL.

Comment: Do you use a navigation case in your faces-config.xml?

Comment: @JosefE. I'm not trying to create a table nor am I trying to use ajax and javascript. MY navigation works, but not when the files are in sub directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative path on A.xhtml to B.xhtml

I would advise you use absolute url (relative to the webapp of course)

wherever your actions are:

Change this:

```
public CompanyBean()
{
  companyValue=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
  companyValue.put("Select Company", "choose");
  companyValue.put("AE", "AE/AE.xhtml");
  companyValue.put("BP", "BP/BP.xhtml");
  companyValue.put("CBK", "CBK/CBK.xhtml");
}
```

to (See the preceding forward slash):

```
 public CompanyBean()
    {
      companyValue=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
      companyValue.put("Select Company", "choose");
      companyValue.put("AE", "/AE/AE.xhtml");
      companyValue.put("BP", "/BP/BP.xhtml");
      companyValue.put("CBK", "/CBK/CBK.xhtml");
    }
```

Comment: In this case, I'm editing what I have mapped in the company Bean vs. using a <h:commandLink> since I'm trying to navigate using a drop down menu. Tried what you suggested regardless and it resulted in a resource to available error.

Comment: post your code so that we can see what you are trying to do

Comment: Can you not see it? I have my companyBean and my snippet of html code that contains the <h:selectOneMenu> in my initial comment.

Comment: Thanks for the revision, but it just results in a 404 error. Resource is not availible.